# transpose one set of characters into another set of characters in Splunk

Tags: regex, substitution, splunk, regular-language, rex

I need to replace all the accents in the 5 vowels of the Spanish alphabet using a single replacement regex and 5 capture groups.

In my text I have áéíóúàèìòù and so on. Until now I have this regex:

```
s/(=?[àáÀÁ])|(=?[èéÈÉ])|(=?[ìíÌÍ])|(=?[òóÒÓ])|(=?[ùúÙÚ])/$1$2$3$4$5/g
```

But this regex gives me the same result on each group.

Is there a way of getting a different value on each of the different group? Like so:

group1 ($1)-> A

group2 ($2) -> E

group3 ($3) -> I

group3 ($4) -> O

group3 ($5) -> U

I know how to do this using 5 different regex, but I need to do this in just one. Any thoughts?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way I know of to do this with one stock regular expression (though I'd love to be proved wrong.)

sed has a dedicated command [`y` / transliterate](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-y-_0028transliterate_0029-command) for this kind of case:

```
sed -e 'y/àáÀÁèéÈÉìíÌÍòóÒÓùúÙÚ/aaAAeeEEiiIIooOOuuUU/'
```

However, it won't help you with removing leading `=` from in front of the characters you want to transliterate. Can you combine two sed commands? eg.

```
sed -e '{ y/àáÀÁèéÈÉìíÌÍòóÒÓùúÙÚ/AAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUU/; s/=\([AEIOU]\)/\1/g; }'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Zak.
Do you know if there's a way o doing this transiteration with regular expressions using substitutions? Like this:

`s/àáÀÁèéÈÉìíÌÍòóÒÓùúÙÚ/AAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUU/g`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Sircam I am afraid not. This is why tools like sed and languages like Perl have transliteration commands. Rex uses Perl, so perhaps you could use Perl's `y///` command?

Comment: Thank you very much @Zak.
I just simply wanted to replace the Spanish characters "àáÀÁèéÈÉìíÌÍòóÒÓùúÙÚ" for "aaAAeeEEiiIIooOOuuUU" and with sed as you told me, works perfectly.

Now I need to figure out how (and if) Splunk is able to do this.

Thanks again!!

Comment: No worries, @Sircam! I've edited your post to include splunk in the title and tags. That should help you find someone who can suggest splunk-specific ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zak! :)